# Drupal 7 hook_node_view for book node?

Tags: drupal-7

I'm trying to modify the contents of any book node in a drupal 7 module.

I've tried hook_node_view, hook_node_view_alter, and hook_entity_view
and nothing get's invoked for book nodes. Basic page nodes call them all.

Clearly, I'm missing some basic drupalism here. Are books not really nodes?
Is there some other hook to call?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the hook_entity_load is invoked by book nodes. Would be nice to know more if somebody has a better answer/explanation as to what's going on here.